# Why my Xpath expression only returning part of the href and not the whole href?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

This xpath expression `response.xpath('//a[@class="playerName"]/@href')` in Scrapy shell only returns the latter half of the href I want to scrape.
The website I'm scraping is https://www.premierleague.com/players. My xpath expression is only returning
'/players/63289/Brenden-Aaronson/overview' instead of 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/63289/Brenden-Aaronson/overview'

[Screenshot of the html source code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jSrB.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of links on the web: absolute links and relative links.

Web pages usually link to their internal content using relative links. The browser understands that if I'm on example.com and I click on `/page-1.html` that the link is relative to example.com - `example.com/page-1.html`

Scrapy sees the links as they are on the website - as relative links - and if you want to convert them to absolute ones you can use `urllib.parse.urljoin` function:

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

relative_url = "/foo.html"
print(urljoin(response.url, relative_url))

# in your case:
relative_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="playerName"]/@href').get()
print(urljoin(response.url, relative_url))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: You could also use the urljoin method on the response itself.  `response.urljoin(relative_url)`